# nomalize() method produces 1E+1

Tags: python

I have issue with this Python line of code

```
    transaction.quantity.normalize()
```

It works fine for most of values, However in one case it produced

```
    Decimal('-1E+1')
```

I tried to debug, I found the value of the transaction quantity when this issue occurred and it was

```
    Decimal('-10.000000')
```

How could i reslove this issue ?

Comment: It's doing what it's supposed to do:  produce a canonical representation with no trailing zeroes in the mantissa.  If that's not what you want, then you don't want `normalize()`.  But you didn't say what you _do_ want.

Comment: I want to remove the zeros at the end of it, as this value will be rendered to a Django template, I want it to be rendered as (-10).

Comment: But "-10" _has_ a trailing zero.  That's why `normalize()` will never produce it.  You first need to define precisely what you want.

Comment: Oh sorry, i didn't notice the issue of the trailing zero, the problem is that i print this value in the django template, when it's printed without the normalize()  method, it's printed as  -10.00000, I want to remove the trailing zeros after the decimal (.) so it will be just  -10

Comment: Ok I've understood the issue, I've found a solution for it, thanks a lot

Comment: @SamuelLiew: Wait, why did you put the typo back?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica bad suggested edits, so I revoked all